# Update object values via GET without repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a flat table, which has a script with several objects, like this:

```
var plano_basicoUS = { 
    1: null, // monthly
    2: null, // quarterly
    3: null, // semester
    4: null, // yearly
};

var plano_economicoUS = { 
    1: null, // monthly
    2: null, // quarterly
    3: null, // semester
    4: null, // yearly
};
```

I update the values of each via `$.get`, like this:

```
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=monthly", function(resultado){
    plano_basicoUS[1] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=quarterly", function(resultado){
    plano_basicoUS[2] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=semiannually", function(resultado){
    plano_basicoUS[3] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=annually", function(resultado){
    plano_basicoUS[4] = parseFloat(resultado);
});

$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=monthly", function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[1] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=quarterly", function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[2] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=semiannually", function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[3] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
$.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=annually", function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[4] = parseFloat(resultado);
});
```

Each query of `$.get` returns a value such as: **10.00**, through the PHP file.

Since there are several objects, I would like to not have to repeat the gets for each one.

How can I do this dynamically, noting that each `$.get` has a different URL? Or sequentially, if that's the case.

Comment: You should return `JSON` with all the updated values from the back-end with 1 call, not 20

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I did not understand exactly what you meant.

Comment: Right now, you are sending 8 different requests to do trivial (and highly related) data retrieval. Instead, it makes more sense to do all of the data retrieval with 1 call that returns `JSON` with all the values you seek

Comment: The problem is that I have already created a mini API to do these queries via GET, so it will return only the individual value of each plan, for each periodicity. Is there any other alternative that you know and can expose here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function that contains the common parts. Something like:

```
const timescales = ["monthly","quarterly","semester","yearly"];

function getNumberByTimescale(timescale, index) {
  $.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=" + timescale, function(resultado){
    plano_economicoUS[index] = parseFloat(resultado);
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < timescales.length; i++) {
  getNumberByTimescale(timescales[i], i + 1); // Adding one to match timescales array index with your arrays' keys.
}
```

This is just one way you could do this, but the important part is abstracting repeated work into function.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should avoid sending 1 call for each data. Rather than this you should send 1 call and get all the data and then populate the information in the objects.

If that is not possible, then you can take this alternative of [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when($.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=monthly"), 
    $.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=quarterly"),
    $.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=semiannually"),
    $.get("buscar_valor.php?id=3&periodicidade=annually"),
    $.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=monthly"),
    $.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=quarterly"),
    $.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=semiannually"),
    $.get("buscar_valor.php?id=4&periodicidade=annually")).then(function(){
  plano_basicoUS[1] = parseFloat(arguments[0]);
  plano_basicoUS[2] = parseFloat(arguments[1]);
  plano_basicoUS[3] = parseFloat(arguments[2]);
  plano_basicoUS[4] = parseFloat(arguments[3]);
  plano_economicoUS[1] = parseFloat(arguments[4]);
  plano_economicoUS[2] = parseFloat(arguments[5]);
  plano_economicoUS[3] = parseFloat(arguments[6]);
  plano_economicoUS[4] = parseFloat(arguments[7]);
});
```